# CiviCRM Extended Security Release details

Tags: esr

We are all-in for the CiviCRM Extended Security Release (ESR) version 5.21.3. We've been big CiviCRM fans for a while. It sounds like a great deal. We just have a few questions, which I will post on this forum. 
Does anyone know the proper contact person?
What is the maximum number of monthly or yearly support phone calls or emails?
Are there any support provider partners that can match the published ESR pricing below for small- to mid-tier?
Thank you!

Jamie

Pricing
https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=64

https://www.civicrm.org/esr

Comment: Hi Delton - the ESR (afaik) does not come with any support package, it is purely the code package. If you expect you need support beyond what you can get via SE or Chat then you might need to check out the list of Providers - https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors. If the info about ESR needs to make this clearer then I can pass on some suggestions or you could via info@civicrm.org. Hope that helps.

Comment: While some partners (including us) may be similar in terms of hosting charges that still isn't going to include support package.

Answer (score 1):

There is better information coming which will include a statement along the lines of

> While Extended Security Release provides for longer term stability and fewer upgrades for subscribers, it does not include any additional level of support over and above what is provided via the community. For organizations that need professional support, we recommend working with an expert that specializes in CiviCRM ESR.

Comment: Interesting that the website you link to isn't the official CiviCRM website. Who runs this site?

Comment: That was a link that Josh posted in Chat - so official imo. https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/14it9nbttp8zmfdja4x7tb7ojo but am seeking clarification

Comment: ok - yes i should not have used that link - so have quoted instead. thx